# Get Post Meta without Value

Tags: wordpress

I have a serious problem. I'm working with "advanced Post Fields" plugin in wordpress. I have a lot of values, but if user don't fill one, the default value is 0.

This is the code:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_3', true);
```

Is possible create an If? `If value is 0, display:none` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_3', true);

if($meta) {
  echo $meta
}
```

or

```
if($meta != 0) {
  echo $meta
}
```

Comment: Really thanks!! I put final code for help other people.

<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_2', true); ?>  • <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $meta = get_post_meta($postid, 'telefono_3', true);

if($meta != 0) {
  echo $meta;
} ?>